# git selective revert (equivalent of `git revert --patch`)

Tags: git, git-revert

Is there a preferred method of reverting part of a previous commit, along the lines of partially reverting unstaged changes (`git checkout -p`) and partially adding unstaged changes (`git add -p`)?

i.e. I have a commit several (or even, many) commits back that contains both wanted and unwanted changes and I want to selectively revert some of those changes while keeping others.

My current workflow is not fun:

```
git diff commit commit^ > selective.diff
cp selective.diff selective2.diff
nvim selective2.diff 
# change unwanted - to ' ' and remove unwanted +, then save
rediff selective.diff selective2.diff | rewrite selective2.diff
git apply selective2.diff
```

and pray the patch takes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git revert --no-commit
git reset --patch     # or `git checkout --patch` if you're sure
```

Comment: Can you add more comments on usage? Where do I put the hash of the commit in question, for example?

Answer (score 12):

I can only think of something like

```
git revert commit --no-commit
git reset # now the changes are unstaged
git add -p
...
git commit
```

But I do not know if it is more practicable than your solution, though.